# How to print each string in a list backwards in python

Tags: python

So if I had a list of strings such as

`a = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']`

how would I reverse each string in that list to make

`a = ['elppa', 'ananab', 'egnaro']`

Comment: `[x[::-1] for x in a]`

Comment: This looks like homework. Did you try anything yourself yet?

Answer (score 2):

How do you reverse single string?

```
word = 'apple'
print(word[::-1])
```

So

```
words = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
reversed_words = [word[::-1] for word in words]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how:

```
a = [y[::-1] for y in a]
print(a)  # ['elppa', 'ananab', 'egnaro']
```

Do invest some time reading about [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Indeed. Thanks!